# This submit value make me confused

Tags: html

I face some problem when I use submit.

Here is the code using some template:

```
{% for art in arts %}
    <div class="art">
        <div class="art-title">{{art.title}}</div>
        <div class="art-created">{{art.created}}</div>
        <pre class="art-art">
            {% autoescape on %}
                {{art.art}}
            {% endautoescape %}
        </pre>
        <form action="editArt.html">

            <input type="submit" name="edit" value={{art.title}}>
        </form>
        <hr>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In the form, I want a "edit" button that can hold the value of art.title which I will use to query database, in order to do that, I set value={{art.title}}. But this change the button's name I want it to show. I hope it can show "edit" when this button shows but hold the value of art.title. How to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <form action="editArt.html">
        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{art.title}}">
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
    </form>
```

In your server code you will then be able to access the "title" value that was submitted with the form but users won't be able to see it because `type="hidden"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to stuff the art.title value in a hidden input field within the form, the value of the button is not a value in the traditional sense, but what the button is labeled.